# Firebase database with progressbar

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have a problem. I can't attach `progressbar` to my activity when data loading from Firebase database. I tried to attach progressbar via `Asynctask`,
put firebase listener into `AsyncTask` `doInBackGround`, set visibility in `PreExecute` and `PostExecute` methods,  but `progressbar` doesn't appear. Any help appreciated.

```html
package org.wangjie.wheelview.DirectionActivity.Direction;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeader;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeaderBuilder;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SecondaryDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.IDrawerItem;

import org.wangjie.wheelview.R;
import org.wangjie.wheelview.gameActivity.SixStep;
import org.wangjie.wheelview.sample.TimelineActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ActivityMainDirection extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Direction> gArray;
    TextView mConception,mDescription,mTools,mDirectionTitle,mTitleDirection,mTitleConception,mTitleMethods;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    ImageView mFirstImage;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager,layoutManager2 ;

    private NavigationView mNavigationView;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    int number,i;

    RecyclerView recycler_artist;
    RecyclerView recycler_pictures;

    TextView mTextView;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.scroll_main_direction);

        Toolbar mToolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

         progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        PrimaryDrawerItem item1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(1).withName(R.string.drawer_item_home).withSelectable(false).withTextColor(Color.BLACK);
      //  SecondaryDrawerItem item2 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2).withName(R.string.drawer_paintings).withSelectable(false).withTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        SecondaryDrawerItem item3 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2).withName(R.string.malevichGame).withSelectable(false).withTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        //  item1.withName("A new name for this drawerItem").withBadge("19").withBadgeStyle(new BadgeStyle().withTextColor(Color.BLACK));
//notify the drawer about the updated element. it will take care about everything else1
//create the drawer and remember the `Drawer` result object
        // Create the AccountHeader
        AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.i_007)

                .build();

//Now create your drawer and pass the AccountHeader.Result

        //additional Drawer setup as shown above

        Drawer result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(mToolbar)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        item1,
                        //new DividerDrawerItem(),
                       // item2,
                        item3
                        // new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings)
                ).withTranslucentStatusBar(false).withAccountHeader(headerResult).withActionBarDrawerToggle(true).withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true).withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        // do something with the clicked item :D
                        if(position==1){
                            Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(), TimelineActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                        if(position==2){
                            Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(), SixStep.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                }).withSelectedItem(-1)

                .build();

//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
//        result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

        FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference=database.getReference();
        gArray=new ArrayList<>();

        recycler_artist= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_artist_list);
        recycler_pictures=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_list);

        mDescription= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mDescription);
        mConception= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mConception);
        mTools= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mToolsText);

        mTitleConception=findViewById(R.id.titleConception);
        mTitleDirection=findViewById(R.id.titleDescription);
        mTitleMethods=findViewById(R.id.titleMethods);

        mFirstImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.first_image);
        mDirectionTitle=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_title);

        View targetView = findViewById(R.id.mConceptionLayout);
        targetView.getParent().requestChildFocus(targetView,targetView);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        //recycler_artist.setHasFixedSize(false);
        recycler_artist.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        layoutManager2=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager2.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2,20);
        layoutManager2.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        //recycler_pictures.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager2.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2,20);

        recycler_pictures.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);

        FirebaseCrash.logcat(Log.INFO,"Activity Direction","  WTF  ");

        new Downloader().execute();

//
//
//
//        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener() {
//
//            @Override
//            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
//
//                Log.e("children tag",(dataSnapshot).toString());
//
//                Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
//
//                for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
//
//                    //Log.e("child tag",child.toString());
//
//                        Direction direction = child.getValue(Direction.class);
//                    gArray.add(direction);
//                    Log.e("new_dir_added", direction.toString());
//
//                }
//                Intent intent=getIntent();
//                String srt=intent.getStringExtra("Number_in_list");
//
//                number=Integer.parseInt(srt);
//
//                Log.e("arrSize", gArray.size() +"   " + number)
//                ;
//
//                Log.e("url image erre",(gArray.get(number).toString()));
//                Log.e("image_url", gArray.get(number).getMUrlImage());
//
//                String [] mPictureList=gArray.get(number).getMUrlImage().split(",");
//
//                String [] mArtistListImage=gArray.get(number).getMArtistListImage().split(",");
//
//
//
//               // recycler_artist.setAdapter(new ArtistAdapter(gArray,number));// список художников в Направлении
//              //  recycler_pictures.setAdapter(new HorizontalRVAdapter(gArray,number)); // список картин в направлении
//
//                recycler_artist.setAdapter(new ArtistAdapter(mArtistListImage,number));
//                recycler_pictures.setAdapter(new HorizontalRVAdapter(mPictureList,number));
//
//                mConception.setText(gArray.get(number).getConcept());
//                mDescription.setText(gArray.get(number).getDesc());
//                mTools.setText(gArray.get(number).getTechnique());
//                mDirectionTitle.setText(gArray.get(number).getName());
//
//                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
//                        .load(gArray.get(number).getImage())
//                        .placeholder(R.drawable.papiros)
//                        .into(mFirstImage);
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
//
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
//
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
//
//            }
//        });

    }


    class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Void> {

        private final ProgressBar progress=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

//        public Downloader(ProgressBar progress) {
//            this.progress = progress;
//            Log.e("DownloaderCons", String.valueOf(progress.getId() == R.id.progressBar));
//        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      progress.setMax(100);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            progress.setProgress((Integer) values[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... voids) {
            //return null;
            for (i=0 ;i<20;i++){
   publishProgress(i);

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(30);

                } catch (InterruptedException ie){
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
                databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        Log.e("children tag",(dataSnapshot).toString());

                        Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

                        for (DataSnapshot child : children) {

                            //Log.e("child tag",child.toString());

                            Direction direction = child.getValue(Direction.class);
                            gArray.add(direction);
                            Log.e("new_dir_added", direction.toString());

                        }
                        Intent intent=getIntent();
                        String srt=intent.getStringExtra("Number_in_list");

                        number=Integer.parseInt(srt);

                        Log.e("arrSize", gArray.size() +"   " + number)
                        ;

                        Log.e("url image erre",(gArray.get(number).toString()));
                        Log.e("image_url", gArray.get(number).getMUrlImage());

                        String [] mPictureList=gArray.get(number).getMUrlImage().split(",");

                        String [] mArtistListImage=gArray.get(number).getMArtistListImage().split(",");



                        // recycler_artist.setAdapter(new ArtistAdapter(gArray,number));// список художников в Направлении
                        //  recycler_pictures.setAdapter(new HorizontalRVAdapter(gArray,number)); // список картин в направлении

                        recycler_artist.setAdapter(new ArtistAdapter(mArtistListImage,number));
                        recycler_pictures.setAdapter(new HorizontalRVAdapter(mPictureList,number));
                       mConception.setText(gArray.get(number).getConcept());
                        mDescription.setText(gArray.get(number).getDesc());
                        mTools.setText(gArray.get(number).getTechnique());
                        mDirectionTitle.setText(gArray.get(number).getName());

                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load(gArray.get(number).getImage())
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.papiros)
                                .into(mFirstImage);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });



         //   }

            return null;
        }


            return null;
        }


}}
```

Here is my xml

```html
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    >
        <!-- полосу на тулбаре я убрал, теперь баг появился статус бар выпрыгивает во время прокрутки  -->


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/papiros"
                android:id="@+id/first_image"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"


                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.88">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/main_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="19sp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>


                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>








    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">






            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mConceptionLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mConception"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""


                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="15sp"

                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleConception"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"


                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:text="Концепция"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"

                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Описание"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"

                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"

                    android:textSize="15sp"


                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

                <TextView

                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"

                    android:id="@+id/mDescription"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:text=""

                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/horizontal_artist_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleMethods"

                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Методы и техники"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                    android:textSize="15sp"


                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mToolsText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"


                    android:textSize="15sp"


                    android:text="
"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >



                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/horizontal_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/grey"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there was quite simple solution. I just put progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); into  for (DataSnapshot child : children) {...} loop and here is my code

```js
 databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {




int count=0;


                Log.e("children tag",(dataSnapshot).toString());

                Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

                for (DataSnapshot child : children) {

count++;
                    if(count >= dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()){
                        //stop progress bar here

                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        mTitleConception.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mTitleDirection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mTitleMethods.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }



                    //Log.e("child tag",child.toString());

                        Direction direction = child.getValue(Direction.class);
                    gArray.add(direction);
                    Log.e("new_dir_added", direction.toString());

                }
                Intent intent=getIntent();
                String srt=intent.getStringExtra("Number_in_list");

                number=Integer.parseInt(srt);

                Log.e("arrSize", gArray.size() +"   " + number)
                ;

                Log.e("url image erre",(gArray.get(number).toString()));
                Log.e("image_url", gArray.get(number).getMUrlImage());

                String [] mPictureList=gArray.get(number).getMUrlImage().split(",");

                String [] mArtistListImage=gArray.get(number).getMArtistListImage().split(",");



               // recycler_artist.setAdapter(new ArtistAdapter(gArray,number));// список художников в Направлении
              //  recycler_pictures.setAdapter(new HorizontalRVAdapter(gArray,number)); // список картин в направлении

                recycler_artist.setAdapter(new ArtistAdapter(mArtistListImage,number));
                recycler_pictures.setAdapter(new HorizontalRVAdapter(mPictureList,number));



                mConception.setText(gArray.get(number).getConcept());
                mDescription.setText(gArray.get(number).getDesc());
                mTools.setText(gArray.get(number).getTechnique());
                mDirectionTitle.setText(gArray.get(number).getName());

                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(gArray.get(number).getImage())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.rama)
                        .into(mFirstImage);





            }




            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Initialise instance count to get know when your data loaded.

Comment: Worth noting that if your record is empty, this will not work. `OnChildAdded` only gets called if theres data in your record, if there isnt, it wont get called; leading to a infinite loading loop (as far as the user can see)
 until data is added.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use this library [afollestad/material-dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)

Before start loading show your dialog like this

```
MaterialDialog.Builder builder = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
    .title(R.string.title)
    .content(R.string.content)
    .positiveText(R.string.agree);

MaterialDialog dialog = builder.build();
dialog.show();
```

after finising loading your data dismis your dialog like this

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: thats what i was looking for :).

Answer (score 0):

Is your code running? According to your posted code          `progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);` this will throw error as casting is not done. Correct will be `progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);`. I have used your xml layout and aynctask as below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        new AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void>() {
            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Above java is working fine with your xml layout. It is perfectly showing and hiding progressbar.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set progress bar to your activity parent layout. First find your parent layout by findviewbyid

**then** just create object of progressbar object, you don't need to create any xml for it.

```
 ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(MainActivity.this,null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            yourParentLayout.addView(progressBar,params);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //To show ProgressBar
```

when you want to hide progressBar use `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`